# Getting tons of errors when trying to npm install material-ui

Tags: npm, material-ui

I'm trying to install material-ui but I keep getting a ton of errors when running `npm install` in my terminal:

```
/Users/myname/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.1.0/include/node/v8.h:3639:37: note: candidate function not
      viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
                                    ^
/Users/myname/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.1.0/include/node/v8.h:3642:37: note: candidate function not
      viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
                                    ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:84:
../src/constants.cc:105:11: error: no matching member function for call to 'Set'
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>("kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemXattrMod").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::Ne...
  ~~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/myname/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.1.0/include/node/v8.h:3639:37: note: candidate function not
      viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
                                    ^
/Users/myname/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.1.0/include/node/v8.h:203642 error:s37 generated.
: note: candidate function not
      viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
                                    ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]

found 90 vulnerabilities (49 low, 17 moderate, 24 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

There are many other errors like this. My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "my_project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.10.2",
    "react": "16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "16.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
  }
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening or how I can fix this? My node version is `v14.1.0` and npm is `6.14.4`.